# create/find java class with simple constructor (hour, min) for use extending GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, android, datetime, extends

I want to store a user-specified rough time of day (unspecified date) in a Java object. Can I instantiate a LocalTime object and set its hours and minutes in one line of Java code? Or is there a different, more suitable existing class?
I have insufficient google wizardry to find such. Elaboration follows, and thank you:

< 1 year android/java exp.
I'm extending the GregorianCalendar class and coding a constructor for FutureCal that takes integer hour (0-23) and minute and returns a calendar-ish object with date/time matching the first future occurrence of that hour:minute (will be either today or tomorrow--for notification/reminder stuff). To allow for other constructors that might have two integers, I would like to use or create a TimeOfDay class/type (comprised of integers hour & minute) and use *that* instead as parameter to my constructor. Is this a) possible b) appropriate?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library is a popular and well-worn replacement for the awful mess that is GregorianCalendar, java.util.Date, SimpleTextFormat, and such. Joda-Time works on Android.

## `LocalTime`

Joda-Time offers a [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) to represent a time-only value without any date or time zone. This class has the constructor you want, passing hour and minute values.

## java.time

The new java.time package built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time) also offers a similar LocalTime class. But Java 8 technology is not available for Android.

## Example Code

Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.4.

```
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime( 13, 15 );  // Quarter-hour after 1 PM.
```

You can apply that LocalTime to a DateTime object. So, **Joda-Time already provides everything you are trying to invent**. Here is some example code setting today’s date-time to the desired time-of-day unless that has already passed in which case we slide to tomorrow’s date and re-apply our desired time-of-day.

```
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime( 13 , 15 );  // Quarter-hour after 1 PM.
System.out.println( "localTime: " + localTime );
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ); // Or DateTimeZone.UTC
DateTime today = localTime.toDateTimeToday( timeZone );
DateTime now = DateTime.now(); // You may want to pad an bit of extra time in case now is extremely close to midnight (new day).
if ( today.isBefore( now ) ) {
    // If the local time in question when applied to today has already past, then
    // adjust to tomorrow while accounting for Daylight Saving Time or other anomaly.
    DateTime tomorrowInitial = today.plusDays( 1 );  // Get tomorrow by adding 1 day to today.
    DateTime tomorrow = localTime.toDateTime( tomorrowInitial ); // DST or other anomaly may mean that tomorrow got adjusted to a different time-of-day. Override with our desired time-of-day.
    System.out.println( "tomorrow: " + tomorrow );
    // return tomorrow;
}
System.out.println( "today: " + today );
// return today;
```

When run.

```
localTime: 13:15:00.000
tomorrow: 2014-10-09T13:15:00.000-04:00
today: 2014-10-08T13:15:00.000-04:00
```

Best to avoid java.util.Date. But if required, you may convert from Joda-Time.

```
java.util.Date date = today.toDate();  // Convert from Joda-Time DateTime to java.util.Date.
```

Comment: I just finished writing my own little 'HourMinute' class (without range checking) which worked. But now that I know, I hope to use Joda-Time. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understood all but why not use a Calendar? I mean, you can set the time in a Calendar object.

```
int hour = 'your hour';
int minute = 'your minute';
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour).
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I instantiate a LocalTime object and set its hours and minutes in
>   one line of Java code?

Yes, provided that you are using Java 8 (LocalTime seems new in Java 8):

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(hour, minute);
```

When you are wondering about the behavior of specific classes, it would behoove you to consult their documentation, in this case, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html.  In most cases, you will get your answer faster, plus answers to followup questions.

Comment: No Java 8 for Android.